# Creating Java Client for CMIS-based server

Tags: java, alfresco, opencms, cmis

I am still new in `CMIS` subject , and I am still searching learn about that, What I want to do is to create a Java client that upload  report to any content management that support `"The CMIS v1.0 OASIS Standard Specification".` such as  `Alfresco` , `Documentum` or `Microsoft SharePoint Server` I found that `opencMIS` for `Java` is a good choice ..

But I am still a bit confused about what is required to write such application the communicate with these CMSs ans repositories .

1. Do I need to handle each one alone , or to create it once and it
   will deal with any CMSs that support this standards  ?
2. How the CMIS client will connect to the CMIS-based server. Do we will have authentication data and a communcation endpoint(URL)?
3. Please if possible-briefly- what are the steps required to do to make a CMIS client using OpenCMIS, does it a hard work for who don't have any previous experience in this topic on has a knowledge about xml, http ..etc?

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://chemistry.apache.org/java/opencmis-cookbook.html#connecting_to_sharepoint_2010

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[OpenCMIS](http://chemistry.apache.org/java/opencmis.html) is really there to let you abstract from the low level protocol details such as XML payloads and the like. On the other hand, it's highly advisable to get a grasp of the [protocol](http://docs.oasis-open.org/cmis/CMIS/v1.0/os/cmis-spec-v1.0.html) itself, just to know what's possible and what not, when designing your application.

Also, the idea behind CMIS is that the same library can access all the compliant CMSs without any code change. What happens in reality is that vendors might have specific extensions that might not be fully portable, and your application might need reworking to support a new CMS ([Alfresco aspects](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/CMIS#Aspect_Support) are a good example).

The [page](http://chemistry.apache.org/java/opencmis-cookbook.html) linked by [@Romain Hippeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/313137/romain-hippeau) is providing a number of examples of the OpenCMIS client API usage.

Comment: Ok thank you, What searching about is "Uplaoding reports" to CMIS based servers .. In fact I don't Know the exact meaning of reports in CMIS . Do all of the CMSs that follow CMIS standard can be handled using OpenCMIS without extension . ( What is the meaning of reports in CMSs?)

Comment: Reports are not part of CMIS standard. I assume that "uploading reports" means you have a file ("report") that you have to upload to a CMIS compliant server. If you don't have any special requirement on metadata properties, this use case is supported by all major CMIS enabled CMSs, no extensions involved. See *Creating a document* [here](http://chemistry.apache.org/java/examples/example-create-update.html)